# Mysql Fetching unique conversation users

Tags: mysql

My current table structure

Table private_messages

```
id     user_to     user_from      message      time_sent
 1           1             2         Test       ~DateTime
 2           2             1        Test2       ~DateTime
```

How can I filter out the unique conversations on basis of a user_to or user_from id?

So thats a conversation between 2 ppl user_a and user_b 
returns user_b in POV of user_a
returns user_a in POV of user_b

If I query from POV of user_to I would like to receive something like this

```
User_id      last_message_sent      time_sent
      2                  Test2          ~Last time sent
```